# Rearrange to get subject

Tags: education

I am looking the rearrange the equation to get h2 as the subject.

$$8-3.5 = (0.028)(h2 - 2724.9)$$

Now i have been dividing h2 both sides to get

$$\frac{4.5}{h2} = (0.028(h2 - 2724.9)$$

But this doesnt seem right. Can anyone help please

Comment: You seem to have only divided by $h_2$ on the left-hand side, though. The right-hand side is unchanged. That being said, if you want to have $h_2$ alone on one side, dividing by it so it appears in denominators is probably something you don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$8-3.5 = (0.028)(h2 - 2724.9)$$
$$8-3.5 = 0.028h2 - 76.2972$$
$$8-3.5+76.2972=0.028h2$$
$$80.7972=0.028h2$$
$$h2=\frac{80.7972}{0.028}$$
$$h2=2885.61$$